# Add annotation to image with canvas on small screen without resizing

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, canvas, ionic-framework

I hope you can help me with my problem. I am writing a mobile application with cordova and ionic and we need a function to annotate images before we upload them.

I want to be able to add annotations to an image (at the moment only lines) without resizing the image. But since the screenspace on phones is small i am now using 2 canvas directly placed above each other.

One the first one i render the scaled down image i want to annotate, on the 2nd one i make the annotations. Then i render the original image on 3 canvas and upscale the annotations to the size of the original image.

```
var finalcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctxfinal = finalcanvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        finalcanvas.width = imageObj.width;
        finalcanvas.height = imageObj.height;

        ctxfinal.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
        var canvaslines = document.getElementById("canvasdraw");
        ctxfinal.drawImage(canvaslines, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);

        $scope.editimage.image = finalcanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

This works fine, but the only downside is that the annotations are rather pixely. I assume there must be a library or something which should make things like this easier, but no matter how much i searched i could not find anything. But maybe i used the wrong keywords since i am not a very adept programmer and not a native speaker. Thanks for all your help in advance

Edit: Here is a link to a jsfiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/q97szydq/14/

Comment: could you provide a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have please?

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry for not providing a fiddle from start, i am a bit new to this. Here is the link to the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/q97szydq/13/] (i had to modify the code a bit, but this is generally it) Thanks for looking at my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to store all your points into an array, then redraw them on your new canvas (after you rescaled the points) :

```
var drawnLines = [];
//in your start functions :  
drawnLines.push(["m", x, y]);

//in your move functions :  
drawnLines.push(["l", x, y]);

//then in your hideModal function :  
var ratio = finalcanvas.width/document.getElementById("canvasdraw").width;
ctxfinal.lineWidth = 3*ratio;

for(i=0; i<drawnLines.length; i++){
        var xm = drawnLines[i][1]*ratio;
        var ym = drawnLines[i][2]*ratio;

        switch (drawnLines[i][0]){                  
            case "l" : ctxfinal.lineTo(xm, ym);
            case "m" : ctxfinal.moveTo(xm, ym);
            }
        }

ctxfinal.stroke();
```

```js
    ctx = document.getElementById("canvasdraw").getContext("2d");
    ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvasimg").getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;

    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() { //ion-header-bar
      var MAX_WIDTH = 300;
      var MAX_HEIGHT = 500;
      tempW = imageObj.width;
      tempH = imageObj.height;
      if (tempW > tempH) {
        if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
          tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
          tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
        }
      } else {
        if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
          tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
          tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").height = tempH;
      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").width = tempW;
      document.getElementById("canvasimg").height = tempH;
      document.getElementById("canvasimg").width = tempW;
      ctx2.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);

    };
    imageObj.src = "http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/12900000/Cute-kittens-12929201-1600-1200.jpg";

     // setup to trigger drawing on mouse or touch
    drawTouch();
    drawPointer();
    drawMouse();

    var drawnLines = [];
     //all draw functions have minus 50px height to adjust for header
     // prototype to start drawing on touch using canvas moveTo and lineTo
    function drawTouch() {
      var start = function(e) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - 50;
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        drawnLines.push(["m", x, y]);
      };
      var move = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - 50;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        drawnLines.push(["l", x, y]);
      };
      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").addEventListener("touchmove", move, false);
    };

     // prototype to start drawing on pointer(microsoft ie) using canvas moveTo and lineTo
    function drawPointer() {
      var start = function(e) {
        e = e.originalEvent;
        ctx.beginPath();
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY - 50;
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        drawnLines.push(["m", x, y]);
      };
      var move = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e = e.originalEvent;
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY - 50;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        drawnLines.push(["l", x, y]);
      };
      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").addEventListener("MSPointerDown", start, false);
      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").addEventListener("MSPointerMove", move, false);
    };

     // prototype to start drawing on mouse using canvas moveTo and lineTo
    function drawMouse() {
      var clicked = 0;
      var start = function(e) {
        clicked = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY - 50;
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        drawnLines.push(["m", x, y]);
      };
      var move = function(e) {
        if (clicked) {
          x = e.pageX;
          y = e.pageY - 50;
          ctx.lineTo(x, y);
          ctx.stroke();
          drawnLines.push(["l", x, y]);
        }
      };
      var stop = function(e) {
        clicked = 0;
      };
      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
      document.getElementById("canvasdraw").addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
    };

    var hideModal = function() {

      var finalcanvas = document.getElementById("finalcanvas");
      var ctxfinal = finalcanvas.getContext("2d");
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {

        finalcanvas.width = imageObj.width;
        finalcanvas.height = imageObj.height;

        ctxfinal.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
        ctxfinal.beginPath();

        var ratio = finalcanvas.width / document.getElementById("canvasdraw").width;
        ctxfinal.lineWidth = 3 * ratio;

        for (i = 0; i < drawnLines.length; i++) {
          var xm = drawnLines[i][1] * ratio;
          var ym = drawnLines[i][2] * ratio;

          switch (drawnLines[i][0]) {
            case "l":
              ctxfinal.lineTo(xm, ym);
            case "m":
              ctxfinal.moveTo(xm, ym);
          }
        }

        ctxfinal.stroke();

        //I then generate a a image from this final canvas. So now i have the image in the original size + the sadly a bit pixely annotations
        //$scope.editimage.image = finalcanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      };
      imageObj.src = "http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/12900000/Cute-kittens-12929201-1600-1200.jpg";



    };
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="buttons" style="height:50px;">
    <button class="button button-clear" onclick="hideModal()">save</button>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvasdraw" style="position:absolute;background:transparent;z-index:99;"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:300px;">
  <canvas id="finalcanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But i am not sure if i can follow you correctly. You mean i can could draw the image to a canvas as big as the image and than scale that canvas using css to display it on the phone? If yes then this would probably be the ideal solution for me, but how would i go about to scale it? If i understand this correctly than i need to be the width/height parameters to be the size of the image to draw the whole image on it or am i wrong? Edit: Are you mabe talking about this css parameter:" transform: scale(x,y);" ?

Comment: Well I'm not sure this is the ideal solution, as I don't know how your touch events will be handled with a rescaled canvas, I think I will remove this idea from the answer, but if you want to dig into it, have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale or even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale

Comment: Okay thanks for the 2 links: I will experiment a bit more and see if touch events work properly with scaling or if i have resort to storing the points in array. I also just discovered that [http://fabricjs.com/] offers the ability to convert a canvas into an svg. Maybe i could convert my annotiations into an svg so i can scale them without loosing resolution. Anyway thanks a lot for your help and your 2 tipps!